# Why does “inferus” have /f/ rather than /d/?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, consonants, phonology, proto-italic

I found various sources indicating that the Latin word inferus (or infer) comes from a Proto-Indo-European form like *n̥dʰer, the source of English “under” and Sanskrit *adhara, adhas.* (The Sanskrit cognate(s) are mentioned in [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=inferus&la=la#lexicon) and *[A Concise Etymological Dictionary of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ak8JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA218&lpg=PA218&dq=etymology%20inferus&source=bl&ots=eW9VCiWY40&sig=lcFg2YK6N9JWnWIkhV1882g-exE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin_dSJorfUAhVk34MKHdNgDt44ChDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=etymology%20inferus&f=false)* (Walter William Skeat, 1885); the reconstructed PIE form and connection to English “under” is mentioned in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inferus).)

Skeat further says that it is a comparative form, which kind of sounds plausible to me, although I don’t know if this is considered correct by modern scholars.

The thing that's puzzling to me is why Latin has “in**f**er(us)” rather than “in**d**er(us)”, since the regular word-medial reflexes of PIE voiced aspirates in Latin were voiced stops rather than voiceless fricatives. (For example,  Wiktionary says  PIE *n̥bʰrís developed to Latin “[imber](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/imber#Latin)”.)

Was PIE *n̥dʰer (or if the “r” is part of a comparative suffix, *n̥dʰ- or whatever) a compound of the negative morpheme *n̥- and some other morpheme? It doesn’t seem obvious to me what the second morpheme would mean. Or was it not originally a compound, but later reinterpreted as one in Proto-Italic or something like that? I’m wondering if there’s any explanation of the phonological/morphological development that gave us “inf” in this word in Latin.

As far as I know, all other instances of “nf” in Latin can fairly easily be explained as the result of compounding: *[Aspects of the Phonology and Morphology of Classical Latin](http://real-d.mtak.hu/896/7/dc_1106_15_doktori_mu.pdf),* by András Cser says:

> The overwhelming majority of the nasal vowel + [f] cases are prefixed forms consisting of *in-* or *con-* plus an *f*-initial stem (*conferre* ‘collect’, *infamis* ‘disreputable’), but see also the simplex *inferus* [ĩːferus] ‘lower’ and its derivatives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Weiss (*Hist. Comp. Gramm. Lat.* 75, note 26) says that "the first syllable of *īnferus* was identified with *in-* and the medial *dʰ was therefore given a pseudo-initial treatment".

De Vaan (s.v.) agrees, citing Walde-Hoffman, Leumann, and Meiser, though he also mentions the possibility of a divergent dialectal treatment. He compares *-fāriam* "in *n* parts" (e.g. *bifāriam*), Skt. *(dvi-)dhā*, where according to Weiss the *f* again results from a pseudo-initial treatment within an analyzable compound.

Comment: @sumelic, he doesn't say; I was assuming prepositional too. It seems a little ad hoc to me, to be honest, but there doesn't appear to be a better explanation.

Comment: And Weiss also mentions quite interesting examples (with medial f) on pp 474-475.

Comment: de Vaan clearly says that "because *en was metanalysed as the preposition 'in'. As for a possible dialectal and other hypotheses (de Vaan cites Giacomelli 1963 but Leumann mentions Meillet), Leumann dismissed those as " entbehrlich und meist sehr kuenstlich."